# Implicit vs Explicit passing of objects

Tags: java, parameter-passing

One of the difference between C function and a java method is that the objects are passed explicitly in C and implicitly in Java,
Can any one provide an example of what implicit and explicit passing pls?

Comment: Could you provide the source of that statement?

Comment: Can you give us a definition of what you mean by explicit and implicit? These aren't normally associated with reference passing , that is, they aren't well known technical terms with agreed-upon definitions in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Java if it's passed by reference, the reference that gets passed, the pointer I recall it's called in C , is a COPY of the original  pointer and not the original pointer itself.

So there's a memory area with the information about the object. Then there's a pointer TO that memory area. When Java passes by reference, it first COPIES that pointer to the memory area, then passes  that COPY of the pointer as a parameter.

This is all completely separate from the other pass by reference and  pass by value distinction.

Comment: I don't think OP refers to the "passing by value vs. reference" phenomenon.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but perhaps you're looking for how object-oriented style is achieved in C.

Java is a true object-oriented language. This means that it has classes and objects. When you write a method that needs to access the object it was called on, one can use the `this` keyword, which refers to the object in question:

```
int getSomething()
{
    return this._something;
}
```

So the actual value of the `this` keyword is dependent of the object - it's then considered as an implicit argument of the parameter.

However, in C, there are no real classes nor objects. If you want to realize OO-style code, you have to pass the argument corresponding to Java's `this` (i. e., the "object" on which you're calling the "method") *explicitly* to the function. For example in the cURL networking library:

```
CURL *hndl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(hndl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
curl_easy_perform(hndl);
```

is roughly equivalent to some OO code like this:

```
CURL hndl = new CURL;
hndl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
hndl->perform();
```

Note that in C, the "object" is often called a "context" or a "handle" when writing code in this style.